# After updating the connection details to MariaDB, system throws ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, mysql, mariadb

I was advised by my web hosting company to change the 'mysql jdbc connection' details to 'mariadb' as per below in the `getDBConnection()`. 
I have downloaded the MariaDB jar [`mariadb-java-client-1.7.4.jar`] compatible for JDK 1.7 & added jar to the project. 
Removed the existing MySQL jar [`mysql-connector-java-5.1.40-bin.jar`] to avoid any conflict. Clean and build the solution and restarted the tomcat server. While submitting the data system still throws below error. Also while debugging at this point, I am receiving null here `connection = SoccerUtils.getDBConnection();     preparedStatement1 = connection.prepareStatement("insert into mydatabase.registeruser values(default,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)",Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);` 
Any idea Why this is still throwing ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver ?

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
Oct 15, 2018 10:53:57 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [RegisterServlet] in context with path [/MyFirstJavaTest] threw exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.myfirstjavatest.pkg.RegisterServlet.addPlayer(RegisterServlet.java:134)
    at com.myfirstjavatest.pkg.RegisterServlet.doPost(RegisterServlet.java:110)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
//Code below:

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

    public static Connection getDBConnection() {
        String url = "jdbc:mariadb://localhost:3307/";          
        String dbName = "mydatabase";       
        String driver = "org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver";      
        String userName = "root";       
        String password = "mypassword";     

        Connection conn = null;
        try {
            Class.forName(driver).newInstance();
            conn = DriverManager
                    .getConnection(url + dbName, userName, password);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        } finally {
        }
        return conn;
    }
```

Comment: try un-deploying currently deployed applications from tomcat, then restart

Comment: benjamin: How can I do this in Eclipse ?